# How to save my struct as a JSON file in Swift

Tags: json, swift, struct, alamofire

This is my struct whose variables I want to use in my report.

```
 struct report : Codable {
    var question : String
    var AnswersChosen : [String] = [String]()
    var userCount : Int
    var hintCount : Int
```

My report of the user's input, the variable inside is the current question the user is on, the options they have selected and how many times they selected the wrong answer per question

```
var currentReport = [report]()
currentReport.append(report(question:questions[currentQuestion - 1 ],AnswersChosen:answerChosen, userCount:ActionCount, hintCount:hintButtonCount ))
            print(currentReport)
```

The output of this code can be seen as such:

[image]

in my code, I am making use of Alamofire to send a JSON file to Laravel. I want to be able to send the currentReport which records the user's inputs as a JSON file via Alamofire. Hence how do I convert my array to a JSON file? Thanks for any help

Comment: Encode it with `JSONEncoder`. Please name structs always with starting uppercase letter and variables always with starting lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode your array to `Data` using an instance of `JSONEncoder`:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(currentReport)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

and then save the `Data` to a file using `write(to:options:)` function, like this:

```
do {
    if var url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        url.appendPathComponent("reports.json")
        try data.write(to: url)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The complete code might look like this:

```
do {
    let reports = [Report(question: "", userCount: 1, hintCount: 1)]
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(reports)
    if var url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        url.appendPathComponent("reports.json")
        try data.write(to: url)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but I was hoping to get a solution on how I can save my array currentReport as a JSON file

Comment: @AyushiAnand sorry, I got your question wrong. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your edit! I am new to swift so I was really confused about this. Just wanted to clarify , the code for the write(to:options:)  fucntion , where does it go? Cos right now it is giving me an error : 'Cannot find 'data' in scope'

Comment: @AyushiAnand you can put the hole `if` statement inside `do` block of the encoding process. (the above code)